# Debugging kernel panic while in X server

Tags: x11, linux-kernel

I sometimes get kernel panic - when that happens caps lock start blinking. However when this happens while I am in X server, the image just stuck, including mouse cursor and everything.

Is there any way to switch back to console or display the contents of panic message? Is there any way to compile kernel so that it's capable of displaying kernel panic messages even in this situation?

Shortcuts like ctrl + alt + f1 etc don't work in kernel panic.

Comment: Possible duplicate of this post, which describes what is a kernel panic and what workarounds can somebody use for debugging (i.e using kexec): http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1660/what-is-a-kernel-panic

Comment: But I am very well aware of what is kernel panic. How is that a duplicate?

Comment: AFAIK the only reliable solution to escape a kernel panic situation is to setup `kexec` to be executed when kernel panic occurs. The link above explains what is a kernel panic (that you already know) and gives some info about escaping in kernel panic situations.